# Can I enter Italy after a refusal?

Tags: south-african-citizens, denial-of-entry, schengen-visas, customs-and-immigration

I have multiple entry Schengen visa from Italy and I flew to Italy but,  at border control, I was refused entry because there was a mistake with my hotel reservation. I was repatriated back to South Africa.

I want to still fly back to Italy with the same visa because it is still valid.

How can I know if my visa was cancelled or if I still can use it?

Comment: My check out date and my return flight date did not match

Comment: My hotel reservation check out date and my return flight date don't match.it was showing that after my return flight back to south africa I will still be having 5 more days at my hotel reservation

Comment: Why would you have a reservation of 5 more days at the hotel? And most of all, if it was a mistake, would the border control not pick up the phone and ask the hotel?

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems likely that your visa is still valid. Since they had your passport already, if the border guards wanted to revoke or annul your visa, they would have altered the sticker and given you some document about your situation.

Being refused entry without annulling the visa is a situation foreseen by the regulations and official guidance so it's not necessarily that surprising. If that's really what happened to you then your visa is still valid and you can certainly re-enter the Schengen area. As explained in [Can a person that has been refused entry to a Schengen country, re-enter to other Schengen country, if no visa is required?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/can-a-person-that-has-been-refused-entry-to-a-schengen-country-re-enter-to-othe), being refused entry does not carry any sort of automatic ban. Currently, information about decisions to refuse entry are not even shared consistently.

Comment: Yes they did give a pepper to sign, and it was saying that I was refused entry because I got no correct document of stay

Comment: And they didn't stamp on my visa or the page next to it but rather they open other page and put a stamp on it

Comment: Plz I really need help

Comment: @Bernard It's possible it wasn't but it's also possible it was, in fact, revoked. I can tell you about the rules and possibly recognise the wording but how could I guarantee anything? I obviously don't have your passport and documents before me nor can I guess what happened. What does the paper say *exactly*?

Comment: That I was refused entry because of non a appropriate documentation justifying the purpose and conditions of away.  That is all.

Comment: @Bernard That's a standard reason to refuse entry that would not usually justify revoking a visa.